# Need to add a class to a <tr> if answer is Yes

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form and want to add a class to the entire row the `<td>` is in if the answer is `"Yes"`. Basically, if the answer from the server comes back `"Yes"` after the form is submitted, the entire row should change color.

This is what I have so far, which only returns the `"Yes"`, but with the correct background color. All I want is the `<tr>` to use the class `colorize`.

```
<?php
if ( ($row['designcapacity']) == 'Yes' ) 
{
    echo "<td class='colorize'>".$row['designcapacity']."</td>";
}
?>
```

Comment: why is javascript/jquery tagged this looks like a php problem as there is no js code

Comment: *"All I want is the `<tr>` to use the class colorize"* - You meant `td`, right? There's no `tr` in your code. I'm a stickler when it comes to detail ;-)

Comment: Correct. I am looking for the <td> to come back as Yes. If it does, then I wanted to have the entire row that the <td> is in have the colorize class.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using PHP would be to check if the answer is = Yes and then echo out the proper  instead of the  tag. I think this is what you are asking for...

```
  if ( ($row['designcapacity']) == 'Yes' ){
       echo  "<tr class='colorize'>";
  }
  else{ echo "<tr>"; }

  echo "<td>".$row['designcapacity']."</td>";
  //additional tds

  echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The content that was returned from the form is basically being displayed in a table grid. So, if the <td> came back as Yes, I wanted to have the entire <tr> that the <td> is in to now have the colorize class. The echo you mentioned is adding a row to the content that is already there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$class = $row['designcapacity'] == 'Yes' ? ' class="colorize"' : '';
echo "<td $class>{$row['designcapacity']}</td>";
```

or merged in one line

```
echo "<td".($row['designcapacity'] == 'Yes' ? ' class="colorize"' : '').">{$row['designcapacity']}</td>";
```